# React native: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'SplashScreen.preventAutoHide')

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

My react native app was working just fine before I used `expo eject`. I ejected it because I now intend to build and release the app to the ios app store. As soon as I attempt to start the ejected app using `react-native run-ios` after it's been ejected I get the exception below.

Please could someone help to understand what's causing this issue and how to tackle it?

react Native versions as follows:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.61.5
```

[image]

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'SplashScreen.preventAutoHide')

This error is located at:
    in AppLoading (at AppLoading.js:52)
    in AppLoading (at App.js:464)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:40)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:101)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

preventAutoHide
    SplashScreen.js:4:21
AppLoading#constructor
    AppLoadingNativeWrapper.js:6:8
renderRoot
    [native code]:0
runRootCallback
    [native code]:0
renderApplication
    renderApplication.js:52:52
runnables.appKey.run
    AppRegistry.js:116:10
runApplication
    AppRegistry.js:197:26
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    [native code]:0
```

Comment: This issue was also raised in the Expo Github repo now: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/7740

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As its evident from docs , SplashScreen is an inbuilt api for expo apps, and since you ejected it , it throws an error since it cant be used.

You can see this in the docs [expo splashscreen](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-splash-screen) .

First you should download `npm i expo-splash-screen`

And then change  your import statement to :

```
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: I don't ever import SplashScreen anywhere and yet get the same error. It remains after installing `expo-splash-screen`

Comment: For me I had to go the path of expo build folder inside node module and replace the previous import method.

Comment: here is the path: `node_modules/expo/build/launch/splashScreen.js`

Answer (score 11):

The [AppLoading component](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading/) is not available in the bare workflow. As @gaurav-roy said you have to refactor your code.

1. Install the `expo-splash-screen` package with `npm install expo-splash-screen`
2. Add a splash-screen to your Android and iOS projects. Run `npm run expo-splash-screen --help` and follow the instructions of this CLI tool. (Because of a bug you might have to run the command again with the `-p "ios"` flag if it only adds the SplashScreen for Android after running it.
3. Change your code inside `App.tsx` in a similar way as in [this example](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-splash-screen#splashscreenpreventautohideasync-in-component-that-initially-renders-null).

   If you're working with hooks you probably want to add an `useEffect`
   hook with an empty dependency list which runs an async function. Here an example of how it could be done:

```
const App = (props: Props) => {
  const [isLoadingComplete, setLoadingComplete] = useState(false);
  
  const init = async () => {
  try {
    // Keep on showing the SlashScreen
    await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
    await loadResourcesAsync();
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(e);
  } finally {
    setLoadingComplete(true);
    // Hiding the SplashScreen
    await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  }, []);

  const renderApp = () => {
    if (!isLoadingComplete && !props.skipLoadingScreen) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <Main />
    );
  };
  return <StoreProvider>{renderApp()}</StoreProvider>;
}
```

Comment: Cheers @andru - I tried auto generating the splash scree with the command you mentioned but that command just hung for ages so eventually I just decided to create it manually.

Comment: @user3391835 The same happened to me. Although it hangs, its creating the Android screens. Then run the command again with the `-p "ios"` option as I mentioned. Then it will create the iOS splash screens. Give it a try.

Comment: Ok - great. Thanks a lot - will try this

Comment: Do we have to use expo splash screen for the app?

Comment: @KehlinSwain No, you don't. You can also use https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen

Answer (score 1):

After looking through this SO page and then digging into some links, especially [this](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-splash-screen#splashscreenpreventautohideasync-in-component-that-initially-renders-null) expo page where they kind of provide a solution for this, I was able to get my app running after about 3 hours of struggle. They haven't added any functional component example, so I am sharing my code below in case someone came here looking for the solution.

```
import { Asset } from "expo-asset";
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Platform, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';

import AppNavigator from "./navigation/AppNavigator";

export default props => {
  const [isLoadingComplete, setLoadingComplete] = useState(false);

  const theme = {
    ...DefaultTheme,
    roundness: 2,
    colors: {
      ...DefaultTheme.colors,
      primary: "#E4002B",
      accent: "#E4002B",
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async function asyncTasks() {
      try {
        await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
      }
      await loadResourcesAsync()
      setLoadingComplete(true);
    }

    asyncTasks()
  }, []);

  return (
    !isLoadingComplete && !props.skipLoadingScreen ? null :
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {Platform.OS === "ios" && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
      <AppNavigator />
    </View>
  );
}

async function loadResourcesAsync() {
  await Promise.all([
    Asset.loadAsync([
      require("./assets/images/logo.png") // Load your resources here (if any)
    ]),
    Font.loadAsync({
      // You can remove this if you are not loading any fonts
      "space-mono": require("./assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf"),
    }),
  ]);
  await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me for an ejected expo app. Looks like expo was referencing it wrongly.
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/7718#issuecomment-610508510

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was updating node_modules/expo/build/launch/splashScreen.js to the following as suggested by adamsolomon1986 [in the repo (issue #7718)](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/7718):

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
import* as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen'
export function preventAutoHide() {
    if (SplashScreen.preventAutoHide) {
        SplashScreen.preventAutoHide();
    }
}
export function hide() {
    if (SplashScreen.hide) {
        SplashScreen.hide();
    }
}
//# sourceMappingURL=SplashScreen.js.map
```

Comment: It's never a good idea to change files in the `node_modules` folder. Anytime you reinstall your dependencies the change will be gone.

Comment: @Andru, thanks for the heads-up; I'll have to watch that. Too bad it was the only thing I found that worked :/

Comment: @Matthew If you absolutely have to do that - you should use patch-package.https://github.com/ds300/patch-package